# Prolog: checking if an unbound set is a subset of a bound set

Tags: prolog, set

I have two sets

```
Set1 = [stone(X),  active(X),  stone(Y),  in(app2,Y),  unlocked(app2)]
Set2 = [stone(s1), active(s1), stone(s2), in(app2,s2), unlocked(app2)]
```

I want my program to recognise that 1 can be a subset of 2 if X is bound to s1 and Y to s2.

The subset function from `library(sets)` is unable to do that, because it can't generate subsets.

I have started playing around with implementing my own subset function which would generate all possible bindings but I don't have much experience in Prolog and the function is becoming very long and clearly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order the sets, using for example `sort`. When you do this the question remains, can the list in `OrdSet1` be unified with a subsequence in `OrdSet2`. This is straight-forward:

```
is_subseq([], _).
is_subseq([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- is_subseq(Xs, Ys).
is_subseq([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- X \= Y, is_subseq([X|Xs], Ys).
```

When you have this predicate, you can do:

```
?- S1 = [stone(X), active(X), stone(Y), in(app2,Y), unlocked(app2)],
|    sort(S1, OrdS1),
|    S2 = [stone(s1), active(s1), stone(s2), in(app2,s2), unlocked(app2)],
|    sort(S2, OrdS2),
|    is_subseq(OrdS1, OrdS2).
S1 = S2, S2 = [stone(s1), active(s1), stone(s2), in(app2, s2), unlocked(app2)],
X = s1,
Y = s2,
OrdS1 = OrdS2, OrdS2 = [active(s1), stone(s1), stone(s2), unlocked(app2), in(app2, s2)]
```

If you want to see the necessary bindings, you have to call it from the interactive interpreter as shown.

Comment: ended up using 
subsetA([], _).
subsetA([H|T], S) :- 
    member_set(H, S), 
    subsetA(T, S).
based on your answer and it seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Nieszka Glad I could help. However, depending on your Prolog implementation, sorting can be very efficient (implemented in C), while `member` needs to traverse the whole list you are checking against every time.

Comment: Thanks @Boris! At the moment I'm on a tight schedule trying to finish it before the deadline but I plan to carry on after my deadline so this will definitely come in useful!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your request, I would write:

```
elements([], _).
elements([E|Es], S2) :-
    select(E, S2, SR),
    elements(Es, SR).

bindings(X, Y) :-
    S1 = [stone(X),  active(X),  stone(Y),  in(app2,Y),  unlocked(app2)],
    S2 = [stone(s1), active(s1), stone(s2), in(app2,s2), unlocked(app2)],
    elements(S1, S2).
```

yields

```
?- bindings(X,Y).
X = s1,
Y = s2 .
```

About subset, I crafted this mini definition (actually I needed it to solve some problem from [project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/about))

```
subset(_, []).
subset(L, [F|T]) :-
    append(_, [F|R], L),
    subset(R, T).
```

but I can't see how could help for your task...